# Games programming literature

Tags: iphone, objective-c, resources

I wonder from years how simple 2D games are "thought".

I mean, if you want to make a game, with a scrolling background, with sprites that move and that collides, with pieces of game representing the (large) level,

- how do you plan to program that ?
- How is the background displayed and loaded ?
- How do you manage complex sprites collisions ?
- How do you manage sprite animation path and velocity ?
- How is the level constructed and loaded to be displayed ?

For exemple, let's talk about a "Sonic" from Sega : a large level, many items placed at many places, a sprite that follow (run) a specific path, ...

- How are all thoses piece of work stored ?
- Loaded ?
- Composed ?

Do you know some literature that could explain me that ?

I plan to apply this to iPhone but I guess it's not really platform specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iPhone, try some of tutorials for game frameworks like [Cocos2D for iPhone](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).

Interesting that you mention Sonic, I recently read an [exhaustive analysis of Sonic physics](http://info.sonicretro.org/Sonic_Physics_Guide). Making a platformer that plays well is harder than you might think!

Also, be aware there is another [Stack Exchange site for game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) where you will find a wealth of other interesting links.